# Find discrepancy between specific columns in 2 worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working with excel, let's say worksheet ABC with columns C3:O102 contains "-" while worksheet DEF with columns C3:O102 contains "yes". I want the cells with discrepancy to return "Discrepancy". I tried excel formulas, I couldn't figure it out so I tried with VBA and it didn't run.

```
Sub IF_Then()
If Worksheets("Sheet15").Range("C3:O102").Value = "-" And Worksheets("Sheet30").Range("C3:O102").Value = "yes" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet30").Range("AJ3:AJ103").Value = "Discrepancy"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel Formula `=Sheet15!C3=Sheet30!C3` should give the result you want I think unless you are specifically looking for "-" and "yes". Returns True/False.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done, using the `IF()` worksheet function, as in my example: I have created two sheets (`Blad1` and `Blad2`), I have filled in cells "A1:A5", and in a third sheet, I've added the following formula in cells "A1:A5" (starting in cell "A1" and dragging down):

```
=IF(Blad1!A1 = Blad2!A1;Blad1!A1;"Discrepancy")
```

(Keep out, my regional settings require semicolons inside a formula, some require commas.)

Comment: @MsPatty: in case my answer helped you or solved your problem, please upvote and/or accept it (this is how this site works).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using it without VBA. I got accurate results with this excel formula. The formula was really long because I was working with a lot of sheets and kind of like dissimilar data.
=IF(AND(INDEX(MATCH),(MATCH)))
I appreciate the contribution